# FindInstance[PrimeQ[f[x]] && x > 70, x, Integers, 1] not working

Tags: functions

Why does

```
f[k_] := k (2^127 - 1) - 1;
FindInstance[PrimeQ[f[x]] && x > 70, x, Integers, 1]
```

not work?

It should find a x for which x*(2^127-1)-1 is prime.

Answer (score 3):

All functions ending in `Q` will *always* return either `True` or `False`.

`PrimeQ[x]` evaluates to `False` if `x` is not an explicit prime number (i.e. if `x` is a symbol or something else).  Thus your

```
PrimeQ[f[x]] && x > 70
```

evaluates to `False` immediately.

The correct way to write this in this scenario is

```
f[x] \[Element] Primes && x > 70
```

But keep in mind that Mathematica's syntax is very general. It can express many more questions than it can answer.  Don't expect useful answers to such difficult questions.